# Populating columns with days based on a selection

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a sleep tracker in Google Sheets ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_1jFANTW9fcm-lrjHqmswlFa7KY-a-SvpSAq0AjcGA/edit?usp=sharing)). The idea is to select a year and a month from a drop-down list in cells A1 and A2, which would then populate columns based on the number of days in that month. I have tried different formulas that I found on stack overflow and elsewhere, but could not get them to work.

In short:

1. I am looking for a formula that will populate the columns with days of that month and a name of the day in a row bellow.
2. Looking for a way to summarize the time of sleep at the end of the each day, based on a ticked checkbox.
3. I am not sure how the year and month selectors should be formatted (as plain number or a date).
4. Is there a way to automatically insert check-boxes to the days of the month?

This is the formula that I have tried to adjust:
=INDEX({TEXT(SEQUENCE(1; DAY(EOMONTH(A2&"/"&A1;0)); A2&"/"&A1; 1); {"d"; "ddd"}); {"Total"; ""}})

But it returns with "Error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

Please note that ";" is used as an argument separator instead of "," (regional settings).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that with a very small adaptation and date formatting you'll be able to easily do it. First with your selector in A2, you could set it as actual dates, but format them as *mmmm*:

[image]

Then, repeat the sequence in both rows starting in C2 and C3:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,DAY(EOMONTH(A2,0)),A2)
```

But formatting row 3 as *ddd*:

[image]

PS: yes, you can do row 3 with TEXT and INDEX. Choose your preferred one:

`=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(1,DAY(EOMONTH(A2,0)),A2),"dddd"))`

### UPDATE with TEXT VALUES

Return to your previous A2 dropdown and try this, using MATCH to find the number of the month, and DATE to locate the correct beginning of the month in that year:

For row 2:

```
    =SEQUENCE(1,DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,MATCH(A2,{"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","September","October","November","December"},0),1),0)),
DATE(A1,MATCH(A2,{"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","September","October","November","December"},0),1))
```

For row 3:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(1,DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,MATCH(A2,{"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","September","October","November","December"},0),1),0)),
DATE(A1,MATCH(A2,{"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","September","October","November","December"},0),1)),"dddd")
```

)

Comment: Thank you. I did put date picker and used formatting (YYYY in A1 and MM in A2), but that could be confusing. So I am looking for a solution that allows selection only of a year or a month but that would be recognized as such.

Comment: When selecting a date with a date picker, the suggested formula will start counting from that date, which could be in the middle of the month. To make this formula populate dates from the beginning to the end of the month I adjusted it to: =SEQUENCE(1;DAY(EOMONTH($A$2;0));EOMONTH($A$2;-1)+1;1)

Comment: If you want to return to values with text in the dropdown, check the update. It will also overcome the problem with the beginning of the month since the use of DATE function

Comment: Thank you Martin, that would indeed solve the problems for point 1 and point 3. I could definitely use the updated formula with text values list in other projects as well!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. Didn't remember you had another question. For point 2, use in C100: `=BYCOL(C4:AG99,LAMBDA(each,COUNTIF(each,TRUE)*TIME(0,15,0)))` and format that row for the expected output format. It will multiply the counts of TRUE values and multiply by 15 minutes. For point 4, it would require a script to auto-adjust

Comment: For the point 4, after additional research I found out that it could be done within a script, but I will try to find a workaround. For the formula provided - the starting value, if no checkboxes are ticked it returns 12:00:00 am. Tried to apply different formatting, but it did not work well. Thanks!

Comment: You can add a condition for that case, to return "", or maybe add some numberlike text' "0:00" `=BYCOL(C4:AG99,LAMBDA(each,IF(COUNTIF (each,TRUE)=0,,""COUNTIF (each,TRUE)*TIME(0,15,0))))`